# Deciphering this path

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://horstmann.com/articles/cygwin-tips.html) in order to install or link to jdk in cygwin

I'm confused about how he wants me to get from my cygwin folder to my Downloads folder.

He says this:

> ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/yourname/Downloads downloads
>
> In the path name for the download directory, replace c: with /cygdrive/c and all backslashes () with forward slashes (/).

So my `cgywin` directory is this:
`D:\cygwin`

My path to downloads is this: `C:\Users\Houseman\Downloads`

I tried this path `/D/C/Users/Houseman/Downloads`, and `C/Users/Houseman/Downloads` but those didn't work.

How do I access my downloads folder, then?

Comment: `/cygdrive/c` is literally `/cygdrive/c`. It's Cygwin's way of accessing the Windows partitions. Just change `/c/` with `/d/` and it'll work.

Comment: @Blender Oh, thanks. However, my Downloads folder is on my `C:\` partition, not my `D:\` partition, so I still need to be able to access that. I changed it to `/cygdrive/c/...` and it worked. If you make it a question, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/cygdrive/c` is literally the path `/cygdrive/c`. It's Cygwin's way of accessing the Windows partitions. Leave it the way it is and it'll work.